# c_str() return value not matching const char*

Tags: c++, string

c_str() returning a const char*, I would assume the following code to print "equal", but it doesn't.

Could someone explain to me where am I wrong ?

```
string xx = "hello";
const char* same = "hello";

const char* buf = xx.c_str();

if (buf == same)
{
    cout << "equal" << endl;
}
```

Comment: == with pointer tests numerical value of pointer. Not data pointed to by pointer.

Comment: You should use strcmp(buf, same) function from string.h http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: @x1Mike7x no, he shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

> I would assume the following code to print "equal"

That's a wrong assumption. `std::string` copies the literal data to its internal buffer, so the pointers will differ.

In case you wanted to compare the data instead of pointers, don't use `c_str()` at all and compare the `const char*` to the `string` directly - the overloaded comparison operator will do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 3):

`operator==` for `const char*` does not do a string comparison, it directly compares the pointers. The buffer used by `xx` is not the same as the `same` pointer, so they are not equal.

To do string comparison with a `std::string` and a `const char*` you can just use the operator provided by `std::string`:

```
if (xx == same)
{
    cout << "equal" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Operator ==` for `char*` pointers compares the pointers themselves, not the strings they point to.

If you want to second-guess std::string, you need to use comparison routines, like following:

```
if (strncmp(buf, same, xx.size())
...
```

Comment: I did and because a) you recommended `strncmp` b) you didn't prefix it with explicit `std::`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, care to elaborate? What's wrong with strncmp **in this context** and why do I have to prefix it with std when a. original example most likely has `using namespace std` in it b. It is not required at all?

Comment: In this context, namely C++, functions from C stdlib should only be used as a compatibility phase when porting C code. They should be avoided in lieu of C++ idiomatic ways when writing new code. And the fact that the code *most likely* might have `using namespace std`, that doesn't mean you should silently follow bad practices.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, disagree completely. The question doesn't stipulate the reason for comparison in this fasion, and I took it to be educational. To me, OP wanted to see how different worlds play together - this is what my 'second guess' comments refer to. I see nothing wrong in playing with C-strings in C++, in fact, I believe it is very useful. As to std prefix for strncmp, like I said, it is not required by any current C++ standard.

Comment: You are of course free to disagree with me. You asked for the reasoning for my downvote, and I've provided it. Nothing you've said is a compelling argument for me to change my mind, so the downvote is here to stay.

Answer (score 0):

`buf == same` is not comparing the strings but the address of the pointers.  Since they are two different variables they will have two different address that will not be equal.  If you need the compare `char*`s or `const char*`s then you can use [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the values of two pointers, which can **never** be equal. `same` points to read-only memory, and the pointer returned by `c_str` is the current data buffer of the `std::string` object with a null terminator guaranteed to be appended.

You *could* write `xx == same`: this is because `std::string` overloads `==` with the appropriate data types. Alternatively, and perhaps less elegantly, you could use `std::strcmp` on the two pointers.